# Identifying the iteration of a For Each loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, iteration

If I have a loop that commences:

```
For each c in Range("A1:C8")
```

Is there a property of the placeholder `c (c.count, c.value, c.something,...)` that identifies the number of times the loop has iterated thus far? I would rather use something like this than including another variable.

Comment: Nope.  You have to count it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a "for each c in range" you can do something like this:

```
Dim c as Long 'presumably you did this as a Range, just change it to Long.
Dim myRange as Range 'Use a range variable which will be easier to call on later
Set myRange = Range("A1:C8")

For c = 1 to myRange.Cells.Count
    'Do something to the cell, identify it as myRange.Cells(c), for example:
    myRange.Cells(c).Font.Bold = True   '<--- replace with your code that affects the cell
Next
```

This allows you to do the exact same For/Next loop, without including an unnecessary counter variable. In this case, `c` is a counter but also serves the purpose of identifying the cell being impacted by the code.

Comment: If you use the `For Each c In Range` syntax, you can use `c.Font.Bold = True` inside the loop, so there is no need for the `Long` variable...

Comment: The problem with this technique is that it requires an index access to get to the cell range which is generally the wole point of the itteration.

Comment: @OlleSjögren there **is** need for the `Long` variable if OP wishes to be able to count the iteration without using an additional counter variable.

Comment: @DaleM Isn't the resulting `c` of each iteration in a `For Each c ...` the same as `myRange.Cells(c)`? So to OP's query, there is a way to do what he wants without the "extra" counter variable. It may not work for everything but in my experience it works on cells in range, specialcells, items in an array, points in series, series in chart, controls on form, shapes on sheet, etc. -- can you give some examples of circumstances where this method wouldn't work so OP can determine what will be the best approach for his problem?

Comment: @DavidZemens OK, maybe the OP needs the counter for something else, but in this answer the only thing the counter is used for is something you don't really need the counter for (setting the font to bold by using an index, when you already have the reference in `c` in the OP code sample).

Comment: @OlleSjögren my example was merely an example (`font.bold = true` was just something I thought of quickly. I don't know what the OP needs or wants the counter for and it doesn't really matter. Yes, he already has a reference to `c` in his code sample, but he wanted a way to index the cell being impacted without creating an additional variable to count the iteration.

Comment: @DavidZemens OK, you win. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to count it yourself like this

```
Dim i as integer
i = 0    
For each c in Range("A1:C8")
    i = i + 1
```

Or

```
Dim i as integer
Dim c as Range
For i = 0 to Range("A1:C8").Count - 1
    Set c = Range("A1:C8").Cells(i)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to add an extra variable to perform the counting, if you structure the loop a little bit differently. You can refer to a cell range like `Range("A1:C8").Cells(c)` as long as `c` is dimensioned as a long/integer.

Answer (score 0):

(Revised)

Using Column or Row properties, as appropriate to the direction you are iterating, you can compute an ordinal number on the fly.  Thus

```
For Each c1 in myRange
    myOrdinal = c1.row - myRange.row + 1       ' down contiguous cells in one column
    myOrdinal = c1.Column - myRange.Column + 1 ' contiguous columns, L2R
Next
```

Comment: I like your idea, but shouldn't it be _myOrdinal = (c1.Row - 1)*myRange.Columns.Count + c1.Column_? As an old C/C++ programmer I assume the for each loop traverses across a row first, then columns, but you know what they say about assumptions. If it's down columns first, then it would be  myOrdinal  = _(c1.Column - 1)*myRange.Rows.Count + c1.Row_.. BTW, is it possible to specify which way the for each loop traverses the range, analogous to the .find function (byRows or byColumns)?